# Time complexity of .NET BCL APIs or Framework methods

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, complexity-theory

Is there any way to know exact time complexity for .NET predefined methods. Like if I want to know the complexity for

```
String.Contains()
```

or

```
 Hashtable.ContainsKey()
```

Does Microsoft share this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in MSDN :)

1. [Hashtable.ContainsKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.containskey.aspx):

> This method is an O(1) operation.

1. [Enumerable.Contains Method (IEnumerable, TSource)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx):

> If the type of source implements
>   ICollection, the Contains method in
>   that implementation is invoked to
>   obtain the result. Otherwise, this
>   method determines whether source
>   contains the specified element.
>
> Enumeration is terminated as soon as a
>   matching element is found.

So, for String it would be O(n).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of posts have mentioned Reflector, which is a good tool but no longer free. A free tool that provides a similar service is [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), worth a look if you don't want to buy reflector.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using a tool like [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1), and looking at the implementation of the methods yourself. You should then be able to determine the complexity for most methods (if they rely on many other methods, it might be cumbersome to trace your way through all the calls to do the calculation).

I do not think there is a page that explicitly lists the complexity for all methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this out yourself very easily using Reflector and the [Code Metrics](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=codemetrics&referringtitle=home&ProjectName=reflectoraddins) addin.

Answer (score 0):

Reflector is an obvious choice to find out the information you need as highlighted in other answers. However, this is no longer a free tool although not too expensive.

A free alternative is to look at the source code for the .NET framework libraries. [Scott Guthrie has a post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx) which provides some information and links to accessing and debugging the source code.